# Using a DIV as an HTML snippet holder

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to render an editable table and I'm evaluating the following approach:

- I prepare the HTML table from the backend with data as labels and an *edit* command
- I prepare an empty row (a `<TR>`) in a hidden DIV with inputs for data and a *save* command
- With jQuery on edit's click I hide the current row and append the filled row available from the DIV's `.html()`

  **UPDATE**: I've added a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdT7R/) to represent this approach

Now, my question is: are there any cons in this approach? Is there a better approach?

I'm concerned about some things:

- a `<TR>` inside a `<DIV>` is non XHTML valid; maybe I can meet some cross browser issues?
- I'd not want the web developer to edit a `<TR>` element via a JS script, to avoid quote escapes, and gain in maintainability

Comment: It's difficult to give any constructive opinion on this because it isn't clear why you're doing this or exactly how — you've given a rough outline of the process but what you're describing is still pretty vague in terms of mechanics and intent. Perhaps a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with a little proof of concept? As far as XHTML validity, why not just put the `<TR>` inside a `<TABLE>` instead of a `<DIV>`?

Comment: While designing UI please keep user experience in mind. Somehow I don't feel this design user friendly( that's my personal opinion ). I would rather try to achieve this:  Prepare the HTML in non-editable mode. As soon as user clicks on any <td>, show one text box over it ( change css to make this text box look like editable <td> ). Now, on pressing <return> save this.  Indeed this is a bit difficult then your approach. But this will look nice.

Comment: I totally agree with you Rakesh (I proposed a dialog with a a form with all the editable data of the row, as an alternative), but in this case the customer expressly asked for this type of interaction so, sadly, I have no choice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered the `contenteditable` attribute? I forked your fiddle to show [how this might work](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/rKF8a/):

When the edit button is clicked, the `contenteditable` attribute is given to the containing row. When the save button is clicked, it's removed. CSS is used to show and hide the right buttons based on the attribute (if you want to support old IE, you might need to change the script to add a class — IE6 can't read attribute selectors).

The way I see it this is a lot less verbose code-wise, and makes the experience a lot more obvious for the user.

Comment: I never knew about this attribute. Thank you for enlightening us!

Comment: +1 You opened a new world to me! I'll go further for a while and try to grab text changes to send them to the server. But I'll ask one more question about this approach: what if I want to add a drop down list to change the content of the field?

Comment: @Andrea How would the dropdown work (that is to say, what would it do)? As the save / edit toggle or as content inside the row?

Yeah, `contenteditable` is awesome. It's actually been around since IE5.5, believe it or not! Bugs can come along when the markup is complex and dynamic — but seeing as you're just editing simple text strings in a table row, it shouldn't get too complicated…

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try to explore this approach:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdT7R/4/)

```
var firstTd = $("td:eq(0)", myTr);
firstTd.html('<input type="text" name="field1" value="' + firstTd.html() + '"/>');
```

Comment: +1 because It's functionally correct, and it may be used; thanks Dark.
But in my case, as I stated above, I'd prefer to have HTML not mixed with JS but picked from another HTML element.

Comment: @AndreaColleoni I'm sure you can edit the idea to fit what you want.